# SwipeEvent para aplicativo Android

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um aplicativo para controle do `SwipeView` mas está funcionando apenas as validações de esquerda para direita e direita para esquerda. As validações cima para baixo e baixo para cima não estão funcionando.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

> Vou compartilhar um código que faz todas as validações e atendeu todas as expectativas que eu queria fazer no *app*, inclusive ele também valida um toque duplo na tela.

Meu novo código (`filtroGestos.java`):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;  
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class filtroGestos extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

public final static int SWIPE_CIMA    = 1;
public final static int SWIPE_BAIXO  = 2;
public final static int SWIPE_ESQUERDA  = 3;
public final static int SWIPE_DIREITA = 4;

public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
public final static int MODE_SOLID       = 1;
public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC     = 2;

private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //um número improvável
private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

private int mode             = MODE_DYNAMIC;
private boolean running      = true;
private boolean tapIndicator = false;

private Activity context;
private GestureDetector detector;
private SimpleGestureListener listener;

public filtroGestos(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

    this.context = context;
    this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    this.listener = sgl;
}

public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

    if(!this.running)
        return;

    boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

    if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
    else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

        if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
        else if (result)
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
        else if(this.tapIndicator){
            event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
            this.tapIndicator = false;
        }

    }
    //Senão não faça nada
}

public void setMode(int m){
    this.mode = m;
}

public int getMode(){
    return this.mode;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean status){
    this.running = status;
}

public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance){
    this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
}

public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance){
    this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
}

public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance){
    this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
}

public int getSwipeMaxDistance(){
    return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
}

public int getSwipeMinDistance(){
    return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
}

public int getSwipeMinVelocity(){
    return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX,
                       float velocityY) {

    final float xDistance = Math.abs(event1.getX() - event2.getX());
    final float yDistance = Math.abs(event1.getY() - event2.getY());

    if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
        return false;

    velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
    velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
    boolean result = false;

    if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
        if(event1.getX() > event2.getX()) // esquerda para direita
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_ESQUERDA);
        else
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DIREITA);

        result = true;
    }
    else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
        if(event1.getY() > event2.getY()) // baixo para cima
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_CIMA);
        else
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_BAIXO);

        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    this.tapIndicator = true;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg) {
    this.listener.onDoubleTap();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

    if(this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC){
        arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);
        this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
    }

    return false;
}

static interface SimpleGestureListener{
    void onSwipe(int direction);
    void onDoubleTap();
}
}
```

SwipeScreen.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SwipeScreen extends Activity implements filtroGestos.SimpleGestureListener {
        private filtroGestos detect;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Detecta area tocada
    detect = new filtroGestos(this,this);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent){
    // Chama o método onTouchEvent da classe filtroGestos
    this.detect.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}
@Override
public void onSwipe(int swipeDirection) {
    String str = "";

    switch (swipeDirection) {

        case filtroGestos.SWIPE_DIREITA : str = "Swipe Esquerda para Direita";
            break;
        case filtroGestos.SWIPE_ESQUERDA :  str = "Swipe Direita para Esquerda";
            break;
        case filtroGestos.SWIPE_BAIXO :  str = "Swipe Cima para Baixo";
            break;
        case filtroGestos.SWIPE_CIMA :    str = "Swipe Baixo para Cima";
            break;

    }
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onDoubleTap() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Toque Duplo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lmontanhine.aulas_android_swipescreen" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lmontanhine.aulas_android_swipescreen.SwipeScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: Acho que seria legal considerar o "delta" do movimento vertical e horizontal, isso é, se houve um maior movimento na vertical do que na horizontal qual deveria ser considerado? E se eu mover na diagonal, qual vai ser o resultado? De resto eu não vejo problema no seu código.

Comment: Em vez de editar a pergunta com o código correcto coloque uma resposta com ele e aceite ela.

Comment: @ramaral Obrigado por avisar. Farei isso o quanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar `GestureDetector` para movimentos de cima e de baixo, ao invés de `SwipeEvent`, exemplo:

```
package com.exemplo.gesture;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class Main extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
        private GestureDetector movimento;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        movimento = new GestureDetector(this);
    }
}
```

E utilize o SwipeDemo no layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Swipe Demo Exemplo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dip" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
                 <ImageView
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_gravity="center"
                     android:gravity="center"
                     android:layout_margin="10dip"
                     android:id="@+id/image_place_holder"/>
           </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @Kauan Kubaski, mas não entendi a resposta. Até tentei fazer essas alterações mas o código retorna erro em diversos pontos. Já criei um XML com a literal "Swipe Detector" e abaixo exibe as ações através do Toast, mas como eu disse, da forma que implementei o código, quando eu faço o movimento da esquerda par a direita, por exemplo, ele mostra: "Swipe esquerda para direita (OK) junto com a mensagem Swipe Cima para Baixo (Não OK)"...aí que está o problema...as validações não estão sendo feitas corretamente. Abraços.